Can/How to get corner angles with view gizmo?
In fusion 360, I can press the corner of gizmo box to get the intersection of axis to align the view to this. Is there anyway to do similar in blender?
Picture below.


In blender very stuck with xy,zx, etc. I can manually angle it, but, very hard to line up.

Hello, could you clarify your question, please? :)

Is there a button or key, to get to the intersection/trihedron orientation for viewport.?

I believe you just use your mouse or numpad to navigate around the 3d workspace, if that's what you mean. You can click each axis as shown above in your screenshot, but you can also swipe around the viewport with your mouse, use your mouse's keys, or use certain key combinations on your keyboard/numpad.

For example, if you go in the 3d workspace with the default cube, if you select the object and then hit any number on your numpad, it will take you to different angles of the object.

Ok. Thanks.  Will try using numpad. I was hoping was easy way jump between them with gizmo. Gonna try setting up manual views with stored views.

If it doesn't work, let me know and I'll be happy to try to come up with a different solution.

@Starry-EyedDonut Navigating will most likely work, but I guess what is asked for here is a gizmo to click on to switch automatic from orthographic to isometric or maybe dimetric or trimetric view. But unfortunately, Matteh, this does not exist in Blender. I guess what you would have to do is set up up some cameras according to the view you want, then name them meaningful and maybe put them in their own collection. To switch between them there are multiple options, the simplest would be to click on the green camera symbol in the Outliner. This collection could be saved in the startup file.

Let me know if this could be useful for you and if you want an answer that shows you how to do that. Oh, and instead of multiple cameras to switch between there are certainly ways to store those viewing angles in something like custom properties or keyframes and then just use one camera instead of multiple ones.

Thank you. I'm using some custom stored views. Its not perfect but will do for now.
